# Most people I've come across who were (are?) good at math, were (are?) good at physics as well

Tags: tense

> **1.** Most people I've come across who **were** good at math, **were** good at physics as well.
>
> **2.** Most people I've come across who **are** good at math, **are** good at physics as well.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?
Do they convey the same meaning?
Would it be a better choice to go with the first one?

Comment: Normally in the second sentence we'd say "I come across".  Most people I've met who were good at math were good at physics too.  Most people I meet who are good at math are good at physics too.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences mean the basically the same thing, and are grammatically correct, the difference is:

> ...who **were** good in math, **were** good in physics as well.

means: people who **at one time** had ability in A also **had ability** in B, and they may or may not continue to have abilities in either.

> ...who **are** good in math, **are** good in physics as well.

means: people who are **currently** good in A are also **currently** good in B.

I believe the second is used more.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but they differ in the time frame they suggest. We could actually have three versions, each implying a different time frame.

> Most people I came across who were good at math, were good at physics as well.

This implies that I came across them in the past and made the observation in the past. It says nothing about whether they still have those abilities.

> Most people I've come across who were good at math, were good at physics as well.

This implies that the people I come across who used to have one ability also had the other, implying that perhaps they no longer have those abilities.

> Most people I've come across who are good at math, are good at physics as well.

This implies that the people I come across who have one ability also have the other, and presumably still have them both.

There is also a difference in implication between "I've come across" and "I come across". "I've come across" suggests that I came across these people in the past, but don't necessarily meet them any more.  "I come across" suggests that I come across such people regularly in the present.

But notice that these are all degrees of implication and suggestion. You would have to be more specific if it really mattered when you met them and whether they still have the abilities or not.

If you are just suggesting a general correlation between these skills, then these issues don't matter, and the phrases all mean the same thing.

If you are suggesting that such a correlation was true in a particular time, or that you observed it in a particular time, then it does matter, and you probably want to rephrase your statement to make it absolutely clear.